# Processing data from files

Tags: powershell

I'm working on data imported from csv files on which same information appears on different location.
I'm trying to group same information in order avoid processing the file line by line but I didn't find yet if it could be possible to use the group-object command on an already grouped dataset.

I would like to be able to isolate each unique "company" & "IdComp", then each unique contract and finally be able to read each code and proceed action with each code and generate xml file as output.
I have isolated data structure for the example and xml is not mentioned.
However, as console output I would like to be able to get the following structure

```
Company(ie : AZ Corp)
===> Contract (ie : 555)
========> Code (ie : ZA)
========> Code (ie : TX)
...(next company)
```

My test code

```
$csv = import-csv “input.txt” –delimiter ';'
$comp = $csv | Group-Object -Property "company" 

ForEach($company in $comp) {
  Write-Output $company.Name

  ForEach($cont in $company) { 
    Write-Output $cont.Group.contract
  }
}
```

My sample xml looks like :

```
company;idcomp;contract;code
AZ corp;100;555;ZA
AZ corp;100;555;TX
AZ corp;100;567;GT
AZ corp;100;567;HY
AZ corp;100;567;KL
WX corp;109;555;TX
WX corp;109;555;JU
WX corp;109;678;HG
```

Edit :
I finally managed to do it with this code :

```
$csv = import-csv “input.txt” –delimiter ';'
$comp = $csv | Group-Object -Property "company" 

ForEach($company in $comp) {
  Write-Host $company.Name

  ForEach($cont in $company) { 
    $contracts = $cont.Group | Group-Object -Property "contract"
    ForEach($contract in $contracts) {
        Write-Host $contract.Name

        ForEach($codedetail in $contract.Group) {
            Write-Host $codedetail.code
        } 
    }
  }
}
```

Output is :

```
AZ corp
555
ZA
TX
567
GT
HY
KL
WX corp
555
TX
JU
678
HG
```

I'm not sure if it is the efficient /cleaner way to do it. Any advice will be welcome.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Did you start coding the required output? What problem did you encounter?

Comment: your "sample xml" looks like a CSV with a semicolon delimiter.  is that your INPUT data?

Comment: the `Group-Object` cmdlet allows multiple properties for grouping things. [*grin*] try this ... >>> `$Csv | Group-Object -Property Company, Contract` <<< and you will see that the groups are `AZ Corp, 555` and `AZ Corp, 567`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!!!

If you use the `get-help` cmdlet on Powershell for the `Group-Object` cmdlet, you will find this on the Description:

> "If you specify more than one property, Group-Object first groups them by the values of the first property, and then, within each property group, it groups by the value of the next property."

Based on this if you use the following code:

```
    $csv | Group-Object -Property "company","contract"
```

It gives you the following output:

```
Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    2 AZ corp, 555              {@{company=AZ corp; idcomp=100; contract=555; code=ZA}, @{company=AZ corp; idcomp=10...
    3 AZ corp, 567              {@{company=AZ corp; idcomp=100; contract=567; code=GT}, @{company=AZ corp; idcomp=10...
    2 WX corp, 555              {@{company=WX corp; idcomp=109; contract=555; code=TX}, @{company=WX corp; idcomp=10...
    1 WX corp, 678              {@{company=WX corp; idcomp=109; contract=678; code=HG}}
```

Then just slightly change your `ForEach` to:

```
ForEach($company in $comp) {
  Write-Output $company.Name

  ForEach($cont in $company) { 
    Write-Output $cont.Group.code
  }
}
```

Output

```
AZ corp, 555
ZA
TX
AZ corp, 567
GT
HY
KL
WX corp, 555
TX
JU
WX corp, 678
HG
```

Comment: Thanks! I saw your answer after editing my question. I found a way to do it but I'm unsure if it is the best way. With multiple property group, the company is displayed at each loop, I would like to have it once per company.